# Наследованный класс как поле класса

Tags: c++

Есть код:

```
class A
{
    public:
        int c;
};

class B : public A
{};

int main()
{
    B a;
    a.c = 10;
    cout << a.A::c;
}
```

Насколько я понял, это что-то вроде восходящего преобразования. Правильное ли у меня понимание данного синтаксиса и есть ли еще какие-то способы апкастинга и даункастинга без ссылок и указателей в плюсах?

Comment: Наследование есть отношение между классами, в данном случаи В есть А , и его  объекты имеют часть А  плюс еще что то своего, поэтому к В() можно ссылаться через А, и можно получать часть А :     А а; B b; a = b;  Объекту базового класса присвоили базовую часть объекта наследника. Статическое преобразование естественно для таких отношений.

Comment: Вот только у автора вопроса нет такого присваивания.

Answer (score 1):

Класс B наследован от A и получает все от него в "наследство". Обычно, обращение  таким данным "очевидно" для компилятора и он может "догадаться". Но иногда бывает не так. Посмотрите на такое

```
class A
{
    public:
        int c;
};

class B : public A
{
    public:
        int c;
};
```

В этом случае компилятор ругаться не будет, но что делать, если с функций класса B нужно обратится к переменной c класса A? Есть два способа - либо сделать функцию-прослойку (но ее нужно будет делать в классе A!, а это не всегда возможно), либо явно подсказать компилятору, что Вы хотите обратится к переменной класса A, используя такой синтаксис

```
B x;
x.c = 1; // это с класса B
x.A::c = 2; // а это с класса А
```

> Насколько я понял, это что-то вроде восходящего преобразования.

нет, это просто уточнение для компилятора, что бы он точно понимал Ваши намерения.

> апкастинга и даункастинга

это не имеет никакого отношения к преобразованию и приведению.

Comment: Я не понял какое имеет отношение к вопросу обращение к члену производного класса?

Comment: я не понимаю Вашего вопроса

Comment: я хотел сказать базового... .

Comment: автор вопроса спросил о непонятном для него синтаксисе, решив, что это какая то особая форма "восходящего преобразования". я написал, что это такое именно.